# generating maven project inheritance/aggregation diagram

Tags: maven

Anyone knows if it is possible to easily generate maven project inheritance/aggregation diagrams like those found in the link below?

http://sonatype.com/books/maven-book/reference/figs/web/pom_real_multi.png

"Figure 3.5. Enterprise Multi-module vs. Inheritance"

The image was taken from this page:

http://sonatype.com/books/maven-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-best-practice.html

This is useful to quickly understand the structure of large maven projects.

Answer (score 0):

One really quick way to do this if you have Eclipse:

- Install the m2eclipse plugin
- Open your pom.xml, select the 'Dependency Graph' tab
- press Print-Screen to capture the image

If you right-click on the graph, you'll see all kinds of presentation options that you can tweak. You can also use the search & filter controls at the top right of the window to change what's shown.

If you want a graph that is created during your build and stays up to date, you could try [maven-overview-plugin](http://code.google.com/p/maven-overview-plugin/) (not quite the same as your diagram, but looks nice all the same) or [EL4J](http://el4j.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: thanks for the quick response. maven-overview-plugin & el4j looks good for generating dependencies.however,i'm trying to generate pom inheritance/aggregation (those specified in parent and modules/module tags within pom.xml) information, NOT the pom's dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool for this: [POM Grapher](http://source.valtech.com/display/PG/Pom+Grapher) (downloadable [here](http://source.valtech.com/repo/content/repositories/releases/de/valtech/pomgrapher/pomgrapher/0.0.3/pomgrapher-0.0.3-jar-with-dependencies.jar)).